# How to forcibly sync field value beetween treads one time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Code sample

```
    public class MyClass{
        private MyObject myObject;        
        private Object lockObject = new Object();        
        MyObjectFactory factory;

        public MyClass(MyObjectFactory factory){
            this.factory = factory; 
        }

        public MyObject GetObject()
        {
           if (myObject == null){
               lock(lockObject){
                  myObject = factory.Create();
                  //need forcibly sync myObject value beetween all threads here
               }
           }
           return myObject;
        }
    }
```

Instance of **MyClass** shared beetwen several threads. I know that I can use **volatile myObject** and it will synchronize field value on write, but also I will get slow reads. Is it possible synchronize **myObject** value only one time into lock section without **volatile**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code slightly so that it implements the double-check pattern:

```
public MyObject GetObject()
{
    if (myObject == null)
    {
       lock(lockObject)
       {
          if (myObject == null)
          {
              myObject = factory.Create();
          }
       }
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

If your code will only ever run on x86/x64 processors then you don't need the `volatile` keyword as the CPU memory model is strong enough to ensure that other threads will see the change to `myObject` in either the the `if` statement, or definitely in the second `if` statement once the lock has been acquired.

Alternatively you can use the `LazyInitializer` class to hide this from you:

```
   private MyObject myObject;        
   private Object lockObject;        
   private MyObjectFactory factory;
   private bool initialized;

    public MyObject GetObject()
    {
      return LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref myObject, ref initialized, ref lockObject, factory.Create)
    }
```

Here you'll just take the hit of a volatile read on the boolean when the object has already been created. Note that the method will allocate the lock object for you if you've not already created one.

Comment: It's interesting fact about x86/x64 processors. I think it's will be solution for me, because our server use x86 processor. But I have theoretical interest - whether it is possible to resolve the situation in general, without assumptions about processor architecture?

Comment: With new info it's complete solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use delegates in this case. The thread will use the delegate to access a method in the main thread to pass data to it and allow it to be actioned immediately assuming that you did not use join when you created the bew thread.